# Erlang enif_realloc_binary memory copying

Tags: c, erlang

Does `enif_realloc_binary` copy data after `enif_alloc_binary`, when we just trim size?

Code

```
ErlNifBinary output;
enif_alloc_binary(length, &output);
produce_output(input.data, length, &output);
enif_realloc_binary(&output, length - 10);
```

Comment: please describe these functions: enif_alloc_binar(), enif_realloc_binary().  Are they functions written by you or some system function?  If written by you, then we cannot help without LOTS more code.

Comment: these are functions from [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html), a person who knows the answer would know that so i didn't mention that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As you'd expect, if you reduce the size of the binary, it copies only that many bytes to the newly-allocated space, but if you increase the size, it copies all the currently-allocated bytes. See the [`enif_realloc_binary` source](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/erts/emulator/beam/erl_nif.c#L565-L588) for details.